# Style layout assistance

Tags: html, css, sass

I am currently having trouble with some styling and i'm looking for some help. Currently i have a couple of divs which are separated by a grey line, however the content of the div doesn't sit vertically in the middle (i have looked to implement other things online but still can't get it to work for some reason).

I also have an image that needs to be to the left of the title and text (and centred as above) but just can't get it to work!

I have attached my code and screenshots to make it a bit clearer :)

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

```css
.search-result__grey-seperator {
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 5 0;
}

.search-result__question {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.search-result__answer {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.search-result__image {
  height: auto;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.search-result__info-container {
  display: inline-block;
}


/*
//Search.scss

.search-result__grey-seperator {
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
    list-style-type: none; 
    margin: $vr*5 0;
}

.search-result__question {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.search-result__answer {
    font-size: 20px;
}


.search-result__image {
    height: auto;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.search-result__info-container {
    display: inline-block;
}*/
```

```html
<div class="search-container__results">


  <article class="search-result">


    <img class="search-result__image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/240x180" />


    <div class="search-result__info-container">
      <h3 class="search-result__question">some text some text</h3>
      <p class="search-result__answer">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>

    <li class="search-result__grey-seperator"></li>


  </article>


</div>
```

//The image looks centred on this example but needs to be consistent rather than its side, as you can tell the spacing above the grey line is larger and needs to be the same across all divs (if that makes sense, let me know if it doesn't)

[image]

//Image needs to be to the left and content to the right at all times, at the minute it wraps incorrectly

[image]

Comment: Please create a [mcve] - the snippet does not work with the react

Comment: Hello, i have refactored it now - sorry about that!

Comment: Can you find a properly sizede image at https://placeholder.com

Comment: I have changed to a smaller size, hope that helps

Comment: you chould change className to class in your example. The given styling doesn't apply in the snippet

Comment: the given styling is scss - I changed it to CSS but have a $vr variable that is not available

Comment: The aspect ratio is not great - your large image is 2499x1663

Answer (score 1):

If the {result.Title} and {result.Summary} are single line you could try to do it like this:

```css
.search-result__info-container {
    display: inline-block;
    top: calc(50% - 73px);
    position: absolute;
}
```

Edit: 
I'm not sure what you want with the images, but at least one of them should be static of size. See below for another possible implementation.

```css
.search-result{
   position: relative;
}

.search-result__question {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 18px;
}

.search-result__info-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 120px);
    height: 95px;
    margin-left: 120px;
}

.search-result__image {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    max-width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 43px);
    height: 75px;
}

.search-result__grey-seperator {
    padding: 11px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 27px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-container__results">
  <article class="search-result">
    <img class="search-result__image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/240x180" />
    <div class="search-result__info-container">
      <h3 class="search-result__question">some text some text</h3>
      <p class="search-result__answer">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <li class="search-result__grey-seperator"></li>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @kootsj, i have tried to implement that but it seems to screw it all up :( i have refactored it down to pure HTML and SASS if it's clearer now - thank you again!!

Comment: Hello @kootsj, unfortunately not, i had a busy weekend and needed to revisit this, still no luck, the answers didn't work as expected :(

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?
I don't know if you can change the image to a div and set it with `background-image` like I did though.

**Edit:** I guess not.

```css
.search-result {
  display: flex;
}

.search-result__image {
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/240x180');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.search-result__question {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
}

.search-result__answer {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.search-result__grey-seperator {
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-container__results">
  <article class="search-result">
    <div class="search-result__image"></div>
    <div class="search-result__info-container">
      <h3 class="search-result__question">some text some text some text some text some text</h3>
      <p class="search-result__answer">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <div class="search-result__grey-seperator"></div>
</div>
```